# Cursores en MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-cursores

Resulta que estoy dando los cursores en MySQL y tengo que hacer un ejercicio.

```
# HACER UN CURSOR QUE RECORRA LA TABLA PERSONAL Y MUESTRE UNICAMENTE LOS NOMBRES DE LAS PERSONAS CUYA EDAD SEA PAR

USE PRUEBA;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PERSONAL(
    NOMBRE VARCHAR(30),
    EDAD INT
);
INSERT INTO PERSONAL VALUES ('TOMAS',41),('JUAMNA',32),('HATIM',19),('JAVI',22),('SERGIO',26);

DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS miEdad $$
CREATE PROCEDURE miEdad()
    BEGIN
        DECLARE fin BOOLEAN DEFAULT false;
        DECLARE NOMBRE VARCHAR(30);
        DECLARE EDAD INT;
        DECLARE c1 CURSOR FOR SELECT NOMBRE,EDAD FROM PERSONAL;
        DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '02000' SET fin = true;
        OPEN c1;
    c1_loop: LOOP
        FETCH c1 INTO NOMBRE,EDAD;
        IF  fin THEN LEAVE c1_loop;
        END IF;
        IF EDAD%2 = 0 THEN
            INSERT INTO PERSONAL VALUES(NOMBRE,EDAD);
        END IF;
    END LOOP c1_loop;
    CLOSE c1;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Pero al hacer el CALL miEdad(); me devuelve lo siguiente.

```
mysql> call miedad();
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: No veo un ``SELECT NOMBRE WHERE EDAD%2 = 0;``, este cursor solo hace una inserción.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

he puesto un ejemplo de como creo que funcionaria, perdón pero no tengo MySQL instalado espero te sirva.

Se usa una tabla temporal porque no deberías iterar y modificar siempre en la misma tabla puede generar un bucle infinito.

```
USE PRUEBA;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PERSONAL(
    NOMBRE VARCHAR(30),
    EDAD INT
);
INSERT INTO PERSONAL VALUES ('TOMAS',41),('JUAMNA',32),('HATIM',19),('JAVI',22),('SERGIO',26);

-- TABLA A MOSTRAR
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS #PERSONAL_MOSTRAR(
    NOMBRE VARCHAR(30),
    EDAD INT
);

DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS miEdad $$
CREATE PROCEDURE miEdad()
    BEGIN
        DECLARE fin BOOLEAN DEFAULT false;
        DECLARE NOMBRE VARCHAR(30);
        DECLARE EDAD INT;
        
        DECLARE c1 CURSOR 
        FOR SELECT NOMBRE,EDAD FROM PERSONAL;
        DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER 
        FOR SQLSTATE '02000' SET fin = true;
        OPEN c1;
            c1_loop: LOOP
                FETCH c1 INTO NOMBRE,EDAD;
                    IF  fin THEN LEAVE c1_loop;
                    END IF;
                    
                    IF EDAD%2 = 0 THEN
                        INSERT INTO #PERSONAL_MOSTRAR VALUES(NOMBRE,EDAD);
                    END IF;
            END LOOP c1_loop;
        CLOSE c1;
        
        SELECT * FROM #PERSONAL_MOSTRAR;
        DROP TABLE #PERSONAL_MOSTRAR;
    END $$
DELIMITER ;
```